# jQuery find().html() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodes

I am new to JS, this is what I was doing.

I have a rawHtml string, which is just html, when I do

```
$(rawHtml).find('#footer')
```

and I log this, this is what it returns

```
jQuery {
'0': HTMLDivElement {},
'1': HTMLDivElement {},
'2': HTMLDivElement {},
'3': HTMLDivElement {},
'4': HTMLDivElement {},....}
```

So I know for sure it's not empty. But if I do this

```
$(rawHtml).find('#footer').html()
```

it returns undefined. I just want to print out the html, Is there other ways I can do this? And why is it printing undefined?

**EDIT**

The html is very long, the basic structure is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some link">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some link">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some link ">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
</html>
```

For simplicity purposes, footer is waaaay down and more complex, for head it's the same thing, if I do

```
$(rawHtml).find('head').html()
```

returns undefined as well.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of rawHtml?

Comment: @AdamH it's kind of long and huge tho

Comment: Well without seeing some representative sample of the HTML content, it's very hard for anybody to help you.

Comment: @Anna - That's what MCVEs are for: [mcve] :-)

Comment: Then do you have multple div with the id `footer` in this long  string Anna ?

Comment: You question is half, please write more about the variable which you using in selector

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki - If she did, the first would be used (if it were a descendant of one of the top-level elements in the set).

Comment: Your edit doesn't include the `id="footer"` element, so it isn't an MCVE.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki please look at the edit I just made :D I included portion of the html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason `html` would return `undefined` would be if you called it on an empty jQuery set, so that tells us that `find` isn't finding anything.

[`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks within the descendants of the entries in the jQuery set. It looks like your `#footer` is directly in the set (at the top level); that commony happens when you use `$()` to parse HTML. If so, you want [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) rather than `find`.

Example:

```js
var rawHTML =
  "<div id=header>header content</div>" +
  "<div id=footer>footer content</div>";
var footerText = $(rawHTML).filter("#footer").html();
console.log(footerText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, if you're not sure whether the element will be at the top level or a descendant, wrap the whole thing in a `div` and use `find`:

```js
var rawHTML =
  "<div id=header>header content</div>" +
  "<div id=footer>footer content</div>";
var footerText = $("<div>").append(rawHTML).find("#footer").html();
console.log(footerText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Folks, look at the console log screenshot in the question. and moreover, when people use `$()` to parse HTML, this is a common problem/mistake.

Comment: True, but if `$(rawHtml).find('#footer')` is logging 5 elements as the OP suggests, then the issue wouldn't appear to be one of hierarchy. I haven't DV'd just FYI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - It just means that they have five top-level elements. We know `find` returns an empty set, and clearly the OP "knows" (would be bettter if shown!) that there's an `id="footer"` in there. So the logical conclusion is...

Comment: Yeah, I think the OP is badly worded, as that output can only come from logging `$(rawHtml)`, not `$(rawHtml).find('#footer')`.

Comment: Thanks filter works on class and id. But If I want to do a tag like head or body, do I still use filter?

Comment: @Anna - `filter` accepts any CSS selector. Note that if you're looking for something deeper in the hierarchy (not at the top level), you may need `find` (which also accepts any CSS selector). I've just added to the answer to cover the case where you're not sure whether the thing you're looking for is at the top level or somewhere deeper.